# Probability on a colored complete graph

Tags: probability, probability-theory, graph-theory

> For a complete graph of $n$ vertices and $1\leq k \leq n$, color each edges by black or white randomly and independently. Let $X$ be a random variable that tells whenever there exists a complete sub-graph of $k$ vertices with all edges colored by black, $X=1$ when there exists and $X=0$ when there does not. Similarly, let $Y$ be a random variable that tells whenever there exists a complete sub-graph of $k$ vertices with all edges with same color.

I'm looking for a good estimate of $\mathbf{P}(Y=1)/\mathbf{P}(X=1)$, i.e. the smallest constant $c$ such that $\mathbf{P}(Y=1)\leq c.\mathbf{P}(X=1)$. However I don't have any idea how to calculate $\mathbf{P}(X=1)$ or $\mathbf{P}(Y=1)$. Can we calculate one of them?